# Angular 2 - Displaying array of objects in a reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am struggle to display an array of recipe ingredient delays objects in an angular 2 reactive form. My component receives an array of recipe objects from another component (@Input()  s_ingredients: Ingredient[]). I can not work out how I display all of the different ingredients in my html though. Wonder if somebody could please help me?

Below is my component ts code:-

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Ingredient } from '../ingredient';
import { IngredientDetailService } from '../ingredient-detail.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-ingredients-details',
  templateUrl: './recipe-ingredients-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-ingredients-details.component.css'],
  providers: [IngredientDetailService]
})

export class RecipeIngredientsDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form: FormGroup;
  ingredients_arr: Ingredient[] = [];

  // @Output will tell the parent component (AppComponent) that an event happened in this component
  @Output() show_read_recipes_event = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private ingredientDetailService: IngredientDetailService

  ) {  }

  @Input()
  r_id: number;

  @Input()
  s_ingredients: Ingredient[];

  buildIngredientDetails(): FormArray{
    return <FormArray>this.create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form.get('s_ingredients');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      s_ingredientDetails: this.formBuilder.array([ this.buildIngredientDetails() ])
    });

    this.create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form = this.formBuilder.group({
      s_ingredientDetails: this.formBuilder.array(
        this.s_ingredients.map(x => this.formBuilder.group({
          ingredient_name: [x.ingredient_name, [Validators.required]]
        }))
      )
    })

  }


  createRecipeIngredientDetails(): void {
    this.ingredientDetailService.createRecipeIngredientDetails(this.create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form.value)
      .subscribe(
        ingredientDetail => {
          console.log(ingredientDetail);

          this.show_read_recipes_event.emit(
            { title: "Recipe Ingredients details" }
          );
        },
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

Below is my html:-

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form [formGroup]="create_recipe_ingredient_detail_form" (ngSubmit)="createRecipeIngredientDetails()">
        <table class="table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered">
          <tr>
            <th>
              Ingredient Name
            </th>
            <th>
              Quantity
            </th>
            <th>
              Comment
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr formArrayName="s_ingredientDetails" *ngFor="let ingredient of s_ingredients; let i=index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
              <td>
                <div class="form-group">           
                  <!--<label name="ingredient_name" formControlName="ingredient_name" class="form-control" id="ingredient.ingredient_id" ngDefaultControl></label>--> 
                  <input name="ingredient_name" formControlName="ingredient_name" class="form-control" id="ingredient.ingredient_id" readonly />           
                  <input type="hidden" name="ingredient_id" formControlName="ingredient_id" class="form-control" id="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-group">   
                  <input type="text" name="ingredient_qty" formControlName="ingredient_quantity" class="form-control" id="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="form-group">   
                  <input type="text" name="ingredient_cmt" formControlName="ingredient_comment" class="form-control" id="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
                </div>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="hidden" id="hidden_recipe_id" name="hidden_recipe_id" value="{{r_id}}" />             
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Recipe Ingredient Details</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

See my form out (screen shot):-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This code looks good, except :

```
<input type="text" id="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
```

`id` is not used to display a text in an input field.

Instead, use :

```
<input type="text" value="{{ingredient.ingredient_name}}" />
```

or :

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="ingredient.ingredient_name" />
```

Comment: As i understood he wants to use FormArray to display all ingredients

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood too

Comment: Hi. Yes I looked at using FormArray, but i wasnt sure how to loop through all the objects in my object array (s_ingredients).

Comment: Im afraid not :-). Ill edit my post above to show you what I have done. Im struggling to get my head around this FormArray stuff (I have looked at many posts on the internet too). My form is not displaying any ingredients now.